# Calling Entity by Named Constant instead of getsomething on JAVA

Tags: java, enums, constants

I am new to JAVA. This is my first question. Sorry if silly or asked (I consulted a lot about enums/constants but didnt get it).

A class FooEntity is mapped from SQL as shown. I want to return it by a specific "class.name" (like enum works). Instead of using foo.getid() and foo.getname(), I want to use foo.ID and foo.NAME and that would return the variables accordingly.

SQL TABLE "FOO"
Column1 Column2
id...................name
1....................ABC
2....................XYZ

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO", schema...)
class FOOentity {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```java
List<FOOentity> foolist = getDAOService.findall(); // return FOO table
for (foo : foolist)
    if (foo.OPTION1) {
        System.out.println("FOO id / name: " + foo.id + " / " + foo.name);
    }
```

**RESULT: Foo id / name: 1 / ABC**

I was told that using/creating enum for this isnt necessary...i should only create a "constant" inside/for the class itself. Should i declare a static final string and create a specific getter or make a constructor for that string? I cant grasp what to do. Do i need to create a specific sql query to return only a single result?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do more clearly? What is the `OPTION1` boolean field on FOOEntity?

Comment: Actually what I want is to be able to call a row by a name like foo.OPTION1 and foo.OPTION2 instead of having to compare it and use loops to select a specific row. My example was bad sorry. For example, the values of "foo.OPTION1.id" should be 1 and "foo.OPTION2.name" should be XYZ. The boolean part is just me not knowing how to do it. The exercise is about making a constant to acess the class, to make it easier to visualize what row you are working with.

Comment: You should have a method on whatever class `getService` is an instance of which takes an `id` and uses an SQL query to return a single row. I don't understand what you mean by "making a constant to acess the class, to make it easier to visualize what row you are working with". Please edit your question to explain further (don't explain in comments, do it in the question)